# How to create a Windows batch script that opens both WSL Ubuntu and Firefox

Tags: windows, batch-file, firefox, cmd, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to write a pretty simple program -- `test.bat`.  This, of course, will be executed within `command.exe` in Windows.  I would like for this program to start Firefox in Ubuntu but also leave the terminal with Ubuntu running.

I've tried the following lines in the batch file:

```
ubuntu -c firefox
ubuntu /c firefox
ubuntu echo firefox
ubuntu firefox
ubuntu | firefox
```

... but none of these commands are launching Firefox.  Why?

In other words, I'd like to:

- Create batch file on the Windows Desktop
- Be able to double-click the batch file to run
- `command.exe` will run the batch file
- The batch file will run Ubuntu in WSL
- The batch file will open Firefox within Ubuntu

How do I pass the proper arguments to the `ubuntu` command to do this?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that you are able to run Firefox from within the instance (although you don't mention in the question that you can), it's likely that you need environment variables that are set within `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` (perhaps `$DISPLAY`?).

If that's the case, then those likely aren't getting sourced when you attempt to script the launch using the commands you tried.

Try `wsl -e bash -lic "firefox"` to force the login and interactive startup scripts to be sourced.  `wsl.exe` is the more up-to-date way to start WSL, and it's much more flexible than  `ubuntu.exe`.

*Update*

From the comments, it sounds like you want to keep the shell open after launching.  This should be:

```
wsl -e bash -lic "firefox & exec bash -li"
```

I don't have Firefox installed in any of my WSL instances at the moment, but I did test that command-line with `xeyes`, and it worked.

What it does:

- Starts Ubuntu with the first `bash` command, with the login and interactive flags that we discussed above.
- The first `bash` then executes `firefox &` to run it in the background, which allows the next command to run immediately.  Without the `&`, you would need to exit Firefox, and only *then* would it execute the next command.
- After putting Firefox in the background, the `exec bash -li` *replaces* the first `bash` (that launched Firefox) with a new `bash`, allowing the terminal to stay open in the shell.

If you have issues with that in a batch file, try:

```
start wsl -e bash -lic "firefox & exec bash -li"
```

Comment: I'm surprised I got downvoted for that but not a big deal heh.

Thanks for the more up-to-date way to start WSL command, that works. Much gratitude. But it only runs in cmd, not WSL ubuntu terminal. I wanted to have it open terminal and run firefox (not run wsl within cmd). I have gwsl and xhost display enabled too.

How do I pass the arg to start firefox to the ubuntu terminal after the batch opens cmd and run ubuntu. Instead of wsl command. Hope I makes sense?

It's just for "good to know". You're awesome btw :)

Comment: @HollaBigJ on mobile at the moment, but a quick question to make sure I'm understanding you better. Are you saying that you want to have the Ubuntu shell open and Firefox open, but CMD closes after executing the batch file? Or do you want all three of them to remain open -- CMD, Firefox, and the WSL/Ubuntu shell/commandline?

Comment: Yes on the first part. Not keep cmd remains open but keeping terminal and firefox (that executed from terminal) open.

I apologize that my English is not my primary language. I'm native American Sign Language signer. :)

Comment: to execute from windows batch file.

Comment: Neat!  And no worries.  I'm happy to edit for clarity.  I'll update the answer with a tip to keep the terminal running after launching Firefox.

Comment: Oh, and I forgot to address the "downvotes" part.  I can only guess, but given the "offtopic" close votes, it appears that some folks don't really consider this programming.  And, to be fair, it's probably not on-topic, since these are just one-liners on various ways to launch WSL.  Yes, you are doing it from a batch file (perhaps "programming"), but the same commands would be used from the command-line itself.  It was "borderline" to me, and I'm trying to be a bit more lenient on closing, but I can certainly understand why someone might downvote or vote-to-close.

Comment: Understood why it's closed, it is not a problem with me. Thanks for explanation why it's down voted and closed.